# Variables and Objects are getting undefined Error at the time of Deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I have been working on a project and got stuck at the time of deployment on the Vercel, the problem is because of prerendering I guess.
As it is causing my variables/objects undefined which I will get from the users later.
Below is the screenshot of the build log file.

Please let me know what is the issue.

If the issue is prerendering then is there any way by which I can stop prerendering some Next.js component?
This is the error I am getting. It would be a great pleasure if someone can help me:blush:

**COMPONENT WHICH IS GIVING ERROR**

```
function Message({ message: { text, user }, name }) {
    let isSentByCurrentUser = false;
    console.log(text, name, user);

    const trimmedName = name.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (user === trimmedName) {
        isSentByCurrentUser = true;
    }

    return (
        isSentByCurrentUser
            ? (
                <div className={[styles.messageContainer, styles.justifyEnd].join(" ")} >
                    <p className={[styles.sentText, styles.pr10].join(" ")} >{trimmedName}</p>
                    <div className={[styles.messageBox, styles.backgroundBlue].join(" ")}>
                        <p className={[styles.messageText, styles.colorWhite].join(" ")}>{ReactEmoji.emojify(text)}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
            : (
                <div className={[styles.messageContainer, styles.justifyStart].join(" ")} >
                    <div className={[styles.messageBox, styles.backgroundLight].join(" ")}>
                        <p className={[styles.messageText, styles.colorDark].join(" ")} >{ReactEmoji.emojify(text)}</p>
                    </div>
                    <p className={[styles.sentText, styles.pl10].join(" ")} >{user}</p>
                </div>
            )
    );
}
```

Yes, that 'text' is undefined I got it... But it is getting defined as soon as the user enters some text. So that's why my app is working fine on localhost.
But when I am trying to deploy it, it is giving me this undefined error. It might be because of prerendering.

**FROM THE BELOW COMPONENT  "message: { text, user }, name"  are getting passed to the above component.**

```
function Messages({ messages, name }) {
    return (
        <ScrollToBottom className={styles.messages} >
            {
                (messages) ? messages.map((message, i) =>
                    <div key={i}>
                        <Message message={message} name={name} />
                    </div>)
                    : "null"
            }
        </ScrollToBottom>
    )
}
```

Build Logs:

```
13:36:20.290    Cloning completed in 318ms
13:36:20.294    Analyzing source code...
13:36:20.824    Installing build runtime...
13:36:23.365    Build runtime installed: 2540.746ms
13:36:27.075    Installing dependencies...
13:36:43.528    > sharp@0.26.3 install /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/sharp
13:36:43.528    > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
13:36:43.730    info sharp Using cached /vercel/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.10.0-linux-x64.tar.br
13:36:45.285    > @ampproject/toolbox-optimizer@2.7.1-alpha.0 postinstall /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer
13:36:45.285    > node lib/warmup.js
13:36:45.721    Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
13:36:45.721    npx browserslist@latest --update-db
13:36:45.970    [7mAMP OPTIMIZER[0m Downloaded latest AMP runtime data.
13:36:46.337    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
13:36:46.337    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
13:36:46.340    added 473 packages from 1423 contributors in 18.698s
13:36:46.608    37 packages are looking for funding
13:36:46.608      run `npm fund` for details
13:36:46.643    Running "npm run build"
13:36:46.917    > xpro3@0.1.0 build /vercel/workpath0
13:36:46.917    > next build
13:36:47.640    info  - Creating an optimized production build...
13:36:47.658    Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
13:36:47.658    This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
13:36:47.658    You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
13:36:47.658    https://nextjs.org/telemetry
13:37:22.791    info  - Compiled successfully
13:37:22.792    info  - Collecting page data...
13:37:24.624    info  - Generating static pages (0/15)
13:37:24.900    Unhandled error during request: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
13:37:24.900        at Message (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Message/Message.js:1381:5)
13:37:24.901        at d (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
13:37:24.901        at bb (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
13:37:24.901        at a.b.render (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
13:37:24.901        at a.b.read (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
13:37:24.901        at exports.renderToString (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
13:37:24.902        at Object.renderPage (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:851)
13:37:24.902        at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Message/Message.js:630:19)
13:37:24.902        at loadGetInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js:5:101)
13:37:24.902        at renderToHTML (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:1142)
13:37:24.904    Error occurred prerendering page "/components/Messages/Message/Message". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
13:37:24.904    TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
13:37:24.904        at Message (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Message/Message.js:1381:5)
13:37:24.904        at d (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
13:37:24.905        at bb (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
13:37:24.905        at a.b.render (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
13:37:24.905        at a.b.read (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
13:37:24.905        at exports.renderToString (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
13:37:24.905        at Object.renderPage (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:851)
13:37:24.905        at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Message/Message.js:630:19)
13:37:24.906        at loadGetInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js:5:101)
13:37:24.906        at renderToHTML (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:1142)
13:37:24.910    info  - Generating static pages (3/15)
13:37:24.957    Unhandled error during request: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
13:37:24.958        at Messages (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Messages.js:372:24)
13:37:24.958        at d (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
13:37:24.958        at bb (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
13:37:24.958        at a.b.render (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
13:37:24.958        at a.b.read (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
13:37:24.958        at exports.renderToString (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
13:37:24.959        at Object.renderPage (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:851)
13:37:24.959        at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Messages.js:773:19)
13:37:24.959        at loadGetInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js:5:101)
13:37:24.959        at renderToHTML (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:1142)
13:37:24.959    Error occurred prerendering page "/components/Messages/Messages". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
13:37:24.959    TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
13:37:24.960        at Messages (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Messages.js:372:24)
13:37:24.960        at d (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
13:37:24.960        at bb (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
13:37:24.960        at a.b.render (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
13:37:24.960        at a.b.read (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
13:37:24.960        at exports.renderToString (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
13:37:24.960        at Object.renderPage (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:851)
13:37:24.960        at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/components/Messages/Messages.js:773:19)
13:37:24.961        at loadGetInitialProps (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js:5:101)
13:37:24.961        at renderToHTML (/vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:54:1142)
13:37:25.062    info  - Generating static pages (7/15)
13:37:25.250    info  - Generating static pages (11/15)
13:37:26.301    info  - Generating static pages (15/15)
13:37:26.302    > Build error occurred
13:37:26.304    Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
13:37:26.304        /components/Messages/Message/Message
13:37:26.304        /components/Messages/Messages
13:37:26.304        at /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:30:1103
13:37:26.304        at async /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:1:1441
13:37:26.304        at async /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:39:69
13:37:26.304        at async /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:1:1441
13:37:26.305        at async /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:21:731
13:37:26.305        at async /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:1:1441
13:37:26.369    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
13:37:26.369    npm ERR! errno 1
13:37:26.372    npm ERR! xpro3@0.1.0 build: `next build`
13:37:26.373    npm ERR! Exit status 1
13:37:26.373    npm ERR! 
13:37:26.373    npm ERR! Failed at the xpro3@0.1.0 build script.
13:37:26.373    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
13:37:26.382    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
13:37:26.382    npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-02-06T08_07_26_373Z-debug.log
13:37:26.388    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
13:37:30.870    Done with "package.json"
```

And this error is coming from '.next/server/pages/...' means this error is not coming directly from the file that I have created but coming from there whenever I try to make a build file.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the component that's triggering the error (`components/Messages/Message/Message`)?

Comment: Yeah thank you for showing interest, now I have updated the content.

Comment: It seems that at build-time, the `message` prop passed to `Message` might be `undefined` in some cases. I'm assuming you must be retrieving data to populate the component. Make sure the data has all needed fields before passing it down to your components, or handle those cases directly in the component itself.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, the code shouldn't work on my localhost also... 
And yes initially those props are empty but they get the values as soon as the user enters something..  So what is your opinion?? What should I do next!


Also, I have added one content have a look, please : )

Comment: You can add a check for `message` inside your `messages.map` to ensure `message` is not undefined before rendering the component.

Comment: Like this?  **`<Message message={(message) && message} name={name} />`**
Still the same error text not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the @juliomalves

This error can be resolved by Destructuring the passed PROPS, only when once it is checked wheater, it has some value in it or not. Or defined or not
Below is the Usage.

```
function Message({ message, name }) {

if (!message) {
    return null
}

const { text, user } = message;
.
.
.
}
```

if the prop is empty then return null else return any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should check that `message` prop is not `undefined` before rendering the `Message` component.

```js
function Messages({ messages, name }) {
    return (
        <ScrollToBottom className={styles.messages} >
            {messages 
                ? messages.map((message, i) =>
                    message && (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <Message message={message} name={name} />
                        </div>
                    )
                  )
                : null}
        </ScrollToBottom>
    )
}
```

This should prevent the build-time error you're getting.

Comment: I really appreciate this approach but still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error as before? You were getting 2 erros on your original question: one related to `message` being undefined in `Message`; and another one related to `messages` being undefined in `Messages`. This should cover both those cases.

Comment: Yes, same, if you don't mind can I add you to the GitHub repo of this project.
btw this is the one part of the error Error `occurred prerendering page "/components/Messages/Message/Message". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`